# Who insert Angular scripts in ASP.NET Core Angular template project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, angular-cli, asp.net-core-2.1, asp-net-core-spa-services

I created a new [ASP.NET Core 2.1 Angular](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) project.

1. What is interesting is that there is `index.html` file inside `ClientApp/src` which is hosted as default page. I would like to know, which code triggers that `index.html` is served by default?

*In my old application from [universal](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal) template Controllers and Views are used which seems more naturally then serving `index.html` from client code.*

2. When application is runned, some code magically inserts Angular scripts (`inline.bundle.js`, `polyfills.bundle.js`, `vendor.bundle.js`, `main.bundle.js` and `styles.bundle.css`) at the end of `index.html` file? Can someone share some light which code does that?

I want to understand this, because I want to serve content from `RazorPage` instead of static `index.html`, but in order to try anything I need to know a little more about magic behind this template.

Comment: Can someone please explain what's wrong with the question. I did my research before posting, couldn't find an answer and I think is legitimate question. Why we shouldn't use RazorPage instead static page?